# Convert a large number of python lists of lists to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists with 16k rows and 16k columns in python :

Please suggest a method to convert in into a pandas dataframe.

I tried using `pandas.dataframe` method but it shows `memory error` due to large size of lists.

Comment: What about splitting the list and creating multiple dataframes?

Comment: yup could have followed this technique but I need to report the whole  matrix as one excel file.   I will eventually follow this technique if NO other method exists, THANKS

Comment: Did you already trie manually writing to a file?

Comment: NO, I did not try it

Answer (score 0):

Python lists of integers/floats have a large amount of overhead. If you construct this data structure from the very start as either a 2-D NumPy array, or a list of 1-D NumPy arrays, you should be able to reduce memory overhead by quite a lot.